# Failure on `system` definition

Tags: scala, akka

I do not know what could solve the error I am encountering below. I have tried to change the definition of my object or even setting it global, but without success as you might probably understand.

Here is the code:

```
import akka.actor._
import akka.actor.Actor
import akka.actor.Props
import akka.actor.ScalaActorRef
import akka.pattern.gracefulStop
import akka.util._
import java.util.concurrent._
import scala.Array._
import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

sealed trait MSG
case class start(
    target: ActorRef
) extends MSG
case class msgTest(
    content: Int
) extends MSG
case class result(
    content: String
) extends MSG

class tip extends Actor {
    def receive = {
        case start(target) =>
            system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(
                1000 milliseconds,
                target,
                msgTest(3)
            )
            system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(
                1000 milliseconds,
                target,
                msgTest(2)
            )
            system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(
                1000 milliseconds,
                target,
                msgTest(1)
            )
        case result(content) =>
            println ("received | content: " + content)
        case _       =>
            println ("no matching found")
    }

}

class transformationNode extends Actor {
    def receive = {
        case msgTest(content) =>
            if (content == 1) {
                sender ! result("mode 1")
            } else if (2 == content) {
                sender ! result("mode 2")
            } else if (3 == content) {
                sender ! result("mode 3")
            } else {
                println ("wut?")
                sender ! result("mode unknown")
            }
        case _      =>
            println ("wut?")
            sender ! "message unknown"
    }
}

object main extends App {
    val system = akka.actor.ActorSystem("mySystem")
    val tip = system.actorOf(Props[tip], name = "tip")
    val transformationNode = system.actorOf(Props[transformationNode], name = "transformationNode")

    tip ! start(transformationNode)
}
```

Then the error:

```
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /home/plard/wrkspc/prjt3/target/scala-2.11/classes...
[error] /home/plard/wrkspc/prjt3/src/main/scala/proj.scala:13: expected class or object definition
[error] def system = akka.actor.ActorSystem("mySystem")
[error] ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 2 s, completed Aug 12, 2014 6:49:12 PM
```

Comment: Your error does not seem to match your code example.  I don't see a reference to `def system = ...` anywhere in your code example.  I do see a `val system = ` but that's not what the error is about.

Comment: @ cmbaxter: You are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using "system" instead of "context.system".

Also I've modified your source code according to the common (at lease for me) coding style:

```
import akka.actor._
import akka.actor.Actor
import akka.actor.Props
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

sealed trait Msg

case class Start(
                  target: ActorRef
                  ) extends Msg

case class MsgTest(
                    content: Int
                    ) extends Msg

case class Result(
                   content: String
                   ) extends Msg

class Tip extends Actor {

  def receive = {
    case Start(target) =>
      (1 to 3) foreach {
        i =>
          context.system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(
            1000 milliseconds,
            target,
            MsgTest(i)
          )
      }

    case Result(content) =>
      println (s"received | content: $content")

    case _       =>
      println ("no matching found")
  }
}

class TransformationNode extends Actor {

  def receive = {
    case MsgTest(content) if (1 to 3).contains(content) =>
        sender ! Result(s"mode $content")

    case MsgTest(content) =>
        println ("wut?")
        sender ! Result(s"mode $content unknown")

    case _      =>
      println ("wut?")
      sender ! "message unknown"
  }
}

object Main extends App {
  val system = akka.actor.ActorSystem("mySystem")
  val tip = system.actorOf(Props[Tip], name = "tip")
  val transformationNode = system.actorOf(Props[TransformationNode], name = "transformationNode")

  tip ! Start(transformationNode)
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Even though you changed a little bit the behavior of my code, I entirely copied it and it works fine. However, I did expect the output:    [success] Total time: 1 s, completed Aug 13, 2014 9:48:01 AM
    > run
    [info] Running main 
    received | content:  mode 2
    received | content:  mode 3
    received | content:  mode 1
As I am sending the messages in ascending order (1 to 3), I do not understand why the 3 adopts this position in the output. Moreover, when I try descending order, the system writes no output...

Comment: * "did not expect such output"

Comment: The messages order may vary because of the same delay (`1000 milliseconds`). If you will set, for example, `(1000 + i) milliseconds` then the order should be stable. To reverse the `(1 to 3)` order you may use `(1 to 3).reverse` :).

Comment: @ Sergiy Prydatchenko: Thank you for the help. Maybe you understood what I was trying to do with this code: Simulate a heartbeat i.e. sending a message every second after a "start"-message is received to trigger the beginning of the process, and stopping it with a "stop"-message. Is using the `receive()` method -like above- the best way to implement this? Or is there a better way (method + `cancellable`)?

Comment: I would prefer "monitoring actor + cancellable" approach with creation of the `cancellable` on "monitoring" actor start (in `preStart`) and cancelling it when it stops or restarts (in `postStop`).

Comment: @ Sergiy Prydatchenko: What are you imply with "'monitoring' actor"?

Comment: @wipman: I mean an actor which monitors an another actor. Like your `Tip` actor does.